# Turning PayPal Button Into an Image Caption

Tags: jquery, html, css, paypal, figure

My page currently looks like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu3GB.jpg

I tried to turn the button, which includes "Wesson", the drop down menu, and "buy now" into an image caption so that it would sit directly below the drawing of the golden retriever (Wesson). Not only is it not centered below the image, it also has pushed the other images to the right. Ideally, I would actually like the button to go right above the image, I created extra space on the page for this on purpose. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#banner {width:100%}
#banner img {width:100%;height:auto}

nav {width:100%;display:block;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
background-color:#222419}
li {display:inline-block;background-color:#222419;}
nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding: 0 30px; font-size:18px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:#222419;}
nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}

a{float:left;
 margin-right:58px;
 margin-left:58px;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
}

body  {background-image:url("background1.jpg");
   background-size:1710px 1405px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

.white_bg  {background-color:#ffffff;
        padding: 3px;
}

.print   {-webkit-transform:rotate(-15deg);
      transform:rotate(-15deg);
}

.print2   {-webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);
       transform:rotate(15deg);
}

#wesson   {text-align:center;width:250px;}
#stanley  (text-align:center;width:250px;}

-->
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>DrawYourPets.com</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<nav> 
<div style="text-align:center" id="banner">
<img src="drawyourpetsbanner3.jpg" border="0" 
alt="DrawYourPetsBanner3"  title="DrawYourPetsBanner2">
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html"><strong>GALLERY<strong></a></li>
<li><a href="store.html"><strong>STORE</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>
</header>

<section>
<aside>
</aside>

<article>


<p style="text-align:center;font-family:arial">
<font size="4"><strong>Prints, coffee mugs, magnets, 
and postcards are available for every drawing!
</strong>
</font>
</p>

<img class="print" style="float:left;margin-left:210px;
margin-right:25px;margin-top:50px"
 src="wesson_print.jpg" height="180px" weight="160px">
<img class="print2" style="float:left;margin-right:70px" 
src="mug.png" height="290px" weight="290px">
<img class="print" style="float:left;margin-right:125px;margin-top:55px" 
src="magnet.jpg" height="160px" weight="160px">
<img class="print2" style="float:left;margin-right:20px;
margin-top:85px" src="postcard5.jpg" height="120px" weight="120px">
<p style="clear:both;">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</p>

<figure>
<img src="wesson.jpg" height="300" weight="260" style="float:left;
margin-left:250px;margin-right:55px">
<figcaption>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="J4TLYQ4FUR6BC">

<table style="text-align:center">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Wesson">
<p style="text-align:center;font-family:arial">
<font size="4"><strong>Wesson</strong>
</font>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="os0">
<option value="Unframed Print">Unframed Print $50.00 USD</option>
<option value="Coffee Mug">Coffee Mug $10.00 USD</option>
<option value="Refrigerator Magnet">Refrigerator Magnet 
$4.00 USD</option>
<option value="Postcard">Postcard $1.00 USD</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:50px;">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
border="0" name="submit" 
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="buynow" border="0" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
width="1" height="1">
</div>
</form>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<img src="stanley.jpg" height="300" weight="260" 
style="float:left;margin-right:55px">
<img src="archibald.jpg" height="300" weight="260" 
style="float:left;margin-right:50px">
<p style="clear:both;">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<img style="float:left;margin-left:525px;margin-right:50px"
 src="maggie.jpg" height="260" weight="300">


<br>
<br>

</article>

</section>

<footer>
<div style="text-align:center" id="banner">
<img src="banner3.jpg" border="0" alt="Banner3">
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you see what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to put it together for you right now, but what you need to do is create a container div for each of the products.  That container would then have 2 divs within it, one for the graphic and one for the PayPal button.  You can set widths, floats, margins, etc. on the divs so that your image and button are on top of each other with the button centered, and then you'd repeat that container for each product.  The container would have some margin on the right or left to space them all out evenly.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got, what you want to do:

1. Put the title, the drop-down-menu and the button above the image.
2. Center the elements horizontally, with the width of the image as the base.
3. Repeat this pattern for every image
4. Arrange the images next to each other on the same height.

To do this you need some kind of wrapper.
This is an oversimplified example:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-info">
      <h1>Wesson</h1>
      <!-- Add Paypal form code here -->
    </div>
    <img src="wesson.jpg">
  </div>

  <!-- Repeat the .item code for the next item -->

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.item {
  float:left; /* Enable the next item to sit next to this one */
  margin-right: 10px; /* The margin between this and the next item */
  text-align: center; /* Center all text inside the item */
}

/* Avoid extra space after the last item */
.item:last-of-type { margin-right: 0; }

/* Center the dropdown inside the item */
.item select { margin: 0 auto; }

/* A better way would be to give the input a class like .button and use this selector here */
.item input[type="image"] {
  display: block; /* Make it a block level element to force it on its own line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the button inside the item */
}
```

**And a little bit more code explainaition:**
I call every content block an item. The item icludes the image, the title, and the paypal form. The container div (`.item`) shrinks to the width of the largest child element. In this case, the image.
Every other item is centered inside the div. What you get is a block, which expands to its widest child element and expands in height as much as needed.

Now this code can be repeated for the next element. Both of these are floated to the left, whichs lets them fit next to eachother if the parent container (`.wrapper`) is wide enough. `.wrapper` is used to set the boundaries for the item. You can add margins to it to define a position for these elements on the page. If it is wide enough to put 3 items next to each other it will do so, but as soon as it gets to narrow for 3, one will break into the next line.

**A live example**
I put together an example with parts of your code on codepen.
You can see it here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BywgqL?editors=110